# Starting a systemd service via python

Tags: python, systemd

Is there a way to start/restart a systemd service via python?

I know that I can make a system call - but then I also could write this in shell script...

```
from subprocess import call
call(["systemctl", "restart service"])
```

I heared systemd has some python binds, but as far as I saw it they only cover the journal

Comment: So you're looking for a systemd module/package?

Comment: Am I? Well I want to talk with systemd as direct as possible. I don't want to exit the python enviroment and ask the system to do it for me, if there is a way to tap in more directly. Isn't there some kind of API, so I can talk to systemd?

Comment: Understand now, *run systemd command more pythonic.* :P

Comment: And I found [this project](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd), is it helpful?

Comment: Theese are the binds for the journal - so python can write to the log.

Comment: Systemd also has a [DBus API](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/dbus/)

Comment: Well I didn't know about DBus untill now - thanks. I think I was searching for this

Comment: Maybe also there: https://github.com/wiliamsouza/python-systemd (requires a gobject main loop)

Comment: Thats nice - he already made a python api for the dbus api :) - would you care to write an answer - So I could accept it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use systemd's [DBus API](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html) to call the `RestartUnit` method of the `Manager` (need of sufficient privileges, else it won't work)

```
import dbus
sysbus = dbus.SystemBus()
systemd1 = sysbus.get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1', '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
manager = dbus.Interface(systemd1, 'org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager')
job = manager.RestartUnit('sshd.service', 'fail')
```

Comment: I posted a similar follow-up question here: [Starting a users systemd service via python and dbus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42088406/2851664).