# Starting a users systemd service via python and dbus

Tags: python, dbus, systemd

It is possible to use systemd's manager via dbus to control services, e.g: [Starting a systemd service via python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33646374/2851664) using this:

```
import dbus
sysbus = dbus.SystemBus()
systemd1 = sysbus.get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1',     '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
manager = dbus.Interface(systemd1, 'org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager')
job = manager.RestartUnit('test.service', 'fail')
```

However, systemd can also handle user's service files with the `--user` flag, e.g.:

```
systemctl --user start test.service
```

How can the user's manager be used from dbus (with python)? Replacing `dbus.SystemBus()` with `dbus.Bus()` or `dbus.SessionBus()` did not do the trick, as this gives:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dbus.SessionBus() is the correct method to connect to the session bus, as per [dbus-python tutorial](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/tutorial.html)

Based on the error message shown I suspect some other issue with dbus and/or your session. For example, when attempting to connect without a valid session I get a slightly different exception, org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported

I would check systemd logs for further information.