# Enable systemd service via python

Tags: python, service, systemd, dbus

According to [Starting a systemd service via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646374/starting-a-systemd-service-via-python) I can use [D-Bus API](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/dbus/) for starting/stopping Systemd services as following:

```py
import dbus
sysbus = dbus.SystemBus()
systemd1 = sysbus.get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1', '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
manager = dbus.Interface(systemd1, 'org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager')
job = manager.RestartUnit('sshd.service', 'fail')
```

But what if I want to enable a systemd service there. I already tried replacing `RestartUnit` with `EnableUnit`, but I got:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method EnableUnit or interface org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.
```

Comment: Have you read the docs on `EnableUnitFiles()`?

Comment: @Terry Actually I couldn't find the docs and I though they didn't managed to write them yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I figured it out thanks to Terry Spotts.

```py
job = manager.EnableUnitFiles(['ssh.service'], False, True)
manager.Reload()
```

First argument is a list of systemd unit file names.

Second argument is a boolean controls whether the unit shall be enabled for runtime only (true, /run), or persistently (false, /etc).

Third argument is a boolean controls whether symlinks pointing to other units shall be replaced if necessary.