# Start & stop systemd service in python3 on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to use a push button that would look for a service if the service is running, then calling systemctl stop "service", and if its not running then calling systemctl start "service"

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import subprocess


GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


service_name = "record"

def minitor(channel):
    try:

        output = subprocess.run(["systemctl", "status", service_name], capture_output=True)
        status = output.stdout.decode().strip()
        if "inactive" in status:
            subprocess.run(["systemctl", "start", service_name])
            print(f"{service_name} service has been started")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif "Active" in status:
            print(f"{service_name} service is Active so stopping it now")
            subprocess.run(["systemctl", "stop", service_name])

    except OSError as ose:
        print("Error while trying to do something with the service", ose)

    pass


while True:
    try:
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(22,GPIO.RISING,callback=minitor)
        time.sleep(10)
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()

message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n")
GPIO.cleanup() # Clean up
```

Unfortunately, only the first push seems to work then the loop is engaged and so the service starts then stops and start...stop...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't try to parse the output of `systemctl status`. Run `systemctl is-active` and use the return code (`0` means the service is active, anything else means it is not).

Comment: This should be `elif service_name in status:`

Comment: service_inactive = "inactive"

This should be `if service_inactive in status:`

Answer (score 0):

## Event Handling

The main problem is that `add_event_detect` is being called in a loop.  For the *single* event `GPIO.RISING`, you are adding *multiple* (identical) event handlers.  Thus, when a single event occurs (i.e. when you push the button once) *all* event handlers for that event will execute, resulting in the service starting and stopping multiple times.

For example, after 35 seconds, `add_event_detect` has been called 4 times, resulting in the following list of event handlers:

```py
[minitor, minitor, minitor, minitor,]
```

If you then push the button, these 4 event handlers are called in sequence.

### Wait for the Event in the Loop

One solution is to wait for the event using the blocking function [`wait_for_edge`](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/):

```py
# GPIO setup and function definitions ...

while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(22, GPIO.RISING)  # Wait here for a rising edge
    minitor()  # A rising edge was detected; call the event handler
```

With this approach, you cannot do other things while waiting for the event.

### Register the Event Handler Once

Another solution is to register your event handler only once:

```py
# GPIO setup and function definitions ...

GPIO.add_event_detect(22, GPIO.RISING, callback=minitor)  # Register the event handler once

# Wait, or do other things
```

## GPIO Setup and Cleanup

**Unrelated to the main problem**: It is not necessary to set up and clean up the `GPIO` module multiple times.  You can do the setup once at the beginning, and the cleanup using the [`atexit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3850261/23371581)).

For the blocking solution:

```py
import atexit
# Other imports ...

atexit.register(GPIO.cleanup)  # Register the cleanup function
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

# Definition of event handler ...

while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(22, GPIO.RISING)  # Wait here for a rising edge
    minitor()  # A rising edge was detected; call the event handler

input("Press enter to quit\n\n")
```

For the event-based solution:

```py
import atexit
# Other imports ...

atexit.register(GPIO.cleanup)  # Register the cleanup function
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

# Definition of event handler ...

GPIO.add_event_detect(22, GPIO.RISING, callback=minitor)  # Register the event handler once

while True:
    time.sleep(10)

input("Press enter to quit\n\n")
```

## Service Status

**Unrelated to the main problem**: As mentioned in the comments, you should not parse the output of `systemctl status`; rather run `systemctl is-active` and check the return code:

```py
process = subprocess.run(
    ["systemctl", "--quiet", "is-active", service_name],
    stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
)
if process.returncode == 0:
    # Service is active
    ...
else:
    # Service is inactive
    ...
```

Alternatively, use [systemd's D-Bus API](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html) to get the status of the service and to start/stop the service (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33646374/23371581)).